# Image insides UIBubbleTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I am making an iOS chat app. I use `UIBubbleTableView` to display texts and images.

Now ,I want the image can click and it will move to another view (which people can see it in full size). But `UIBubbleTableView` seems doesn't support it, so how can i fix it?

Here is my code in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Something here//
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBubbleData *photoBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithImage:[UIImage         
    imageNamed:@"halloween.jpg"] date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-290]     
    type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
    //something else here//
}
```

With these codes it just shows the image.

Comment: Do you trying to add `UIImage` to `UIBubbleTableView's` cell or you trying to open `UIImage` in another view to see it in full size?

Comment: @zakhej Im trying to open UIImage in another view to see it in full size. It likes Apple Message App :D.

Comment: And what do you have now? Post your code in question.

Comment: @zakhej Sorry for my late reply. I have edited my question. Hope you can help me. Thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 5):

I know this isn't the recommended or ideal way to do it, but this is what I have done for the time being. I will likely come back to it and do it "correctly" later when I find a good way.

For each NSBubbleData object, I add a touch gesture to it's view. When the user touches, the `touchEventOnImage:` method is called. From sender, you can get the gesture recognizer, whose view is that of the UIImageView set by the NSBubbleData. You can display this image full screen.

This is the code I used:

```
- (void)addTouchGestureToBubble:(NSBubbleData *)oBubbleData
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchEventOnImage:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    //Don't forget to set the userInteractionEnabled to YES, by default It's NO.
    oBubbleData.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [oBubbleData.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

- (void)touchEventOnImage:(id)sender
{
    if( [sender isKindOfClass:[UIGestureRecognizer class]] )
    {
        UIGestureRecognizer * recognizer = (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;

        if( [recognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] )
        {
            UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:((UIImageView *)recognizer.view).image];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
            imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            // Remove the corner radius applied in the NSBubbleData class.
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;

            UIViewController * vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
            vc.view = imageView;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you at least make some progress.

Comment: Works! Wouldn't it be nice and cleaner though if this was integrated in the UIBubbleTableViewDelegate? I'm using the for from https://github.com/curioushq/UIBubbleTableView